# NGINX "engine:" interpretation

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm configuring nginx server to use SSL. Configuration looks like this (separate file in conf.d)

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name localhost;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.cer; 
ssl_certificate_key engine:gost_capi:foobar.ru; 
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_ciphers HIGH:MEDIUM:+GOST2001-GOST89;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;
}
}
```

I'm using russian GOST cryptography, In order to access the private key I use "engine:" reserved word. Nginx should access the private key using defined engine, but it interprets is like a file instead. I get an error:

```
file /etc/nginx/engine:gost_capi:foobar.ru not found
```

Why it happens like this?

Comment: What is your Nginx version? This feature is only available since 1.7.9.

Comment: Well, ithought that it was the latest, but actually it's 1.2.